# Can Formmule script be set to report cumulative student lates-to-classes?

Tags: event-triggers

I am using Formmule to report student lates-to-classes. I'd like the script to flag and report to the student, parents, and school administrators the total number of absences once they reach 3, for example, then 6, 9, etc. Is this possible to do? Thank you very much!

Brian.

Comment: If your using google-forms or FormMule then you should add those tags to add visibility to your question.